# "ng-image-viewer" can’t move image which is under drag-scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

*ng-image-viewer* could not move the image inside a parent element which is drag-scroll.

```
@ViewChild('nav', {read: DragScrollComponent, static: false}) ds: DragScrollComponent;
```

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<drag-scroll class="drag-box" style="width: 100%;" #nav>
```

Inside this drag scroll, I have this *ng-image-viewer* element:

```html
<ng-image-viewer class="responsive" [src]="[images]"></ng-image-viewer>
```

Here are my CSS code:

```css
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
  .drag-box {
    width: 1080px;
  }
}
```

Normally I could drag it by double clicking the image and move around, but now that dragging event is taken for its parent element which is drag-scroll.

I want that image to move around when double click on it.